# Prove that there are no integers with order $4$ in modulo $12$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that there are no integers with order $4$  in  modulo $12$

---

This is given as an obvious fact without any proof in my textbook. However I am not able to see why there cannot be any integer whose order is $4$ in $\mod 12$. Any help ? thanks !

Comment: If "order" means additively, then $3$ has order $4$.  If "order" means multiplicatively, then look at $\mathbb{Z}_{12}^\times$.

Comment: That doesn't help. I am looking for an explanation and not references. Order of $a$ in $\mod n$ is the smallest positive integer $k$ such that $a^k \equiv 1 \pmod n$

Comment: @rational, no. What you wrote is the *multiplicative* order of $\;a\;$ in the group of units modulo $\;12\;$ , i.e. in  $\;\Bbb Z_{12}^*\;$. As Vadim explained to you, without further saying your question implies the additive order, meaning: the order in the group $\;\Bbb Z_{12}\;$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [Carmichael function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function),

$$\lambda(12)=\text{lcm}(\lambda(4),\lambda(3))=\text{lcm}(2,2)=2$$

In fact,  $$\lambda(24)=2$$

Comment: I'm sorry may I ask how does that prove there is no $a$ such that $a^4\equiv 1 \mod 12$ ? (4 is minimum possible exponent)

Comment: @rational, Have you followed the link ?

Comment: still going through it, is this right $1^1 \equiv  1 \mod 12$

Comment: sorry for being slow; im hearing Carmichael function for the first time. it seems my textbook skipped this topic

Comment: @rational, $$1^1\equiv1\pmod n,(-1)^2\equiv1$$ for all integer $n$

Comment: Is it possible to prove this by using congruences and $\phi$ function ? Carmichael function is throwing me off at the moment as it is new to me sorry

Comment: @rational, Using $\phi, \phi(4)=\phi(3)=2\implies a^2\equiv1\pmod3,a^2\equiv1\pmod4\implies $ lcm$(4,3)|(a^2-1)$

Comment: okay and $\phi(12) = 4$ , how do these relate to the proof in question exactly ?

Comment: @rational, It implies max(ord$_{12}a)=2$

Comment: The number $12$ is a very small number. Note that $1$ has order $1$. The numbers $2,3,4$ are not relatively prime to $12$, so no power of them is congruent to $1$. Note that $5^2\equiv 1$, so $5$ has order $2$. Continue. Only $2$ more candidates to examine.

Comment: OMG yes! $7^2\equiv  11^2 \equiv 1 \mod 12$ We only had to check for $a \lt 12$ as we are doing $\mod 12$ and all other numbers can be written as $12k+r$ by division algorithm xD I am such a noob thanks a lot awesome people !!!!

Answer (score 6):

Explicitly $\mathbb{Z}_{12}^\times=\{\pm 1, \pm 5\}$, and each of these has order at most 2, e.g. $(-5)^2=25\equiv 1\pmod{12}$.

Comment: nice ! i liked this proof

Comment: I don't get this proof :( I am not familiar with groups :/